# Unable to change local security settings

Tags: windows-xp, group-policy

In Windows XP, I'm going to add a new user with a simple password. It prompts that the password does not meet the password policy requirements. I've not set a policy!
Then I found that i should use gpedit.msc to change this policy. But it's disabled and I'm unable to change the default policy. I don't know how to change this policy.

Comment: Is this an HP laptop by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

Can you use Start -> Run -> secpol.msc, and then navigate to Account Policies and then Password Policy and change it there?

If not, then maybe you can do this by editing the registry directly using this:

[Set strong password policy in Windows XP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/555540)

Comment: I examined it, and it's also unchangeable. I tried registry, but there's no Network section in HKLM/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/policies section!

Comment: it's weird that password policies located on network section!

Comment: I think I should edit the default group policy instead. Do you know how? and why is these entries essentially disabled?!

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I found it! The computer was joined to a domain. So I couldn't create a user with a simple password, even in the local Windows. I left the domain and the fields got changeable!
Microsoft is always weird.